# Cannot convert XML to Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I have an xml that looks something like that. (It's longer so did not paste the whole thing) I am trying to read the mentioned file with read_xml, but it is just printing a table full of NaN Values. how can I resolve it? (Newby in terms of XML files)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from tkinter import filedialog as fd

filename = fd.askopenfilename()
 
df = pd.read_xml('{}'.format(filename), )

print(df)



<ScheduleMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" DtdVersion="3" DtdRelease="3">
  <MessageIdentification v="20211022_DA_POS_65XGENEXMARKET0I" />
  <MessageVersion v="1" />
  <MessageType v="A01" />
  <ProcessType v="A01" />
  <ScheduleClassificationType v="A01" />
  <SenderIdentification v="65XGENEXMARKET0I" codingScheme="A01" />
  <SenderRole v="A01" />
  <ReceiverIdentification v="10X1001C--00007L" codingScheme="A01" />
  <ReceiverRole v="A04" />
  <MessageDateTime v="2021-10-21T10:02:02Z" />
  <ScheduleTimeInterval v="2021-10-21T22:00Z/2021-10-22T22:00Z" />
  <ScheduleTimeSeries>
    <SendersTimeSeriesIdentification v="S_10Y1001A1001B012_65YBG-ENERGRIDDB" />
    <SendersTimeSeriesVersion v="1" />
    <BusinessType v="A02" />
    <Product v="8716867000016" />
    <ObjectAggregation v="A03" />
    <InArea v="10Y1001A1001B012" codingScheme="A01" />
    <OutArea v="10Y1001A1001B012" codingScheme="A01" />
    <InParty v="65YBGGENEX000002" codingScheme="A01" />
    <OutParty v="65YBG-ENERGRIDDB" codingScheme="A01" />
    <MeasurementUnit v="MAW" />
    <Period>
      <TimeInterval v="2021-10-21T22:00Z/2021-10-22T22:00Z" />
      <Resolution v="PT1H" />
      <Interval>
        <Pos v="1" />
        <Qty v="0" />
      </Interval>
```

Comment: kindly share your code, so we can suggest possible improvements

Comment: Hi! I have edited the question and added code itself. Nothing special; I am just grabbing the file and trying reading it through read_xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by validating XML file. Based on the code you have shared, it seems like that this is not a valid XML file.

In order to read XML file through pandas and convert into csv or excel file, you can use pandas_read_xml library:

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
```

And then you can read the file via below code line:

```
df = pdx.read_xml('path-to-your-XML-file.xml')
```

You also need to flatten after reading XML file:

```
df = pdx.fully_flatten(df)
```

Comment: this is the valid XML, I have just pasted just a copy of it. Will try right now your suggested way and let's see. hope it works and will let you know.

Comment: Make sure that your XML file does not contain special characters before feeding into pdx.

Comment: did not work :( Now it is just a weird (1,1) dataframe with 1 element; When I am opening the mentioned xml in the excel, everything is done in a great manner. I want the python to do the same.

Comment: I have added additional codes to my answer. You are right. You need to flatten pdx through fully_flatten function. Please check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I wish I posted question here the very first moment. During googling process none of the methods were including pandas-read-xml; Mostly they were about read_xml method and other different ways. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark your question as answered here. :) You can accept my solution as accepted.